# WordPress localhost admin saving = "The requested URL was not found on this server."

Tags: wordpress, apache

I am running a local install of WordPress. Everything works except for the admin section. Whenever I try to save (for example, in the Settings page) I get this error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /wp-admin/options-general.php was not found on this server.
```

I have set the permissions on options-general.php to 755 (also tried 775) and updated my httpd.conf file to change all instances of `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` but I still can't save anything in the admin section.

Another curious observation is that my Settings URL is:

`http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/options-general.php`

...but when I hit save it removes /wordpress and takes me to:

`http://localhost/wp-admin/options-general.php?settings-updated=true`

Additionally my `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` settings are both set to `http://localhost/wordpress`.

- [httpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/GrPeh4NN)

If there's anything else I can try I would greatly appreciate it.

*P.S. I went to the WordPress StackExchange site, but they said to post Apache errors here.*

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess and httpd.conf files?

Comment: Added my httpd.conf. I dont have an htaccess

Comment: try adding yourself to  the _www group

Comment: If this is a development environment try changing the user and group properties in httpd.conf to yourlogin and restart apache. 

If this is not an option for you
try adding yourself to  the _www group
usermod -G _www yourlogin
then  the chown the Sites directory
chown yourlogin:_www Sites -R
That should eliminate any permission issues, not saying that it will solve the problem but it might point us in a better direction

Comment: Yes, it is a development environment. I'm sure I did something wrong, but I replaced `_www` to my username in `User _www` and `Group _www`. Now WordPress won't load, it just throws an `Unable to connect` error. Anything else I can try?